# unexpected results from static function in C++ class

Tags: c++, syntax, compilation, static-methods

I need a static class function to be able to use GLFW3 mouse callback in C++. When I use an if statement in the function I get wrong results. I made some simple demonstration code. With the more complex mouse callback function that is called by GLFW3 I get similar results.

What am I doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

class StaticTest
{
public:
   StaticTest();
   ~StaticTest();
   int setCallback();
   static void callback(double xpos, double ypos);
};

StaticTest::StaticTest()
{
}

StaticTest::~StaticTest()
{
}

void StaticTest::callback(double xpos, double ypos)
{
   float p;
   static float q;

   p += xpos;
   p += ypos;
   q = p;

   std::cout << "p, q before if: " << p << ", " << q << std::endl;

   if (p > 2*5)
      p = 100;
   if (q > 2*5*p/q)
      q = 100;

   std::cout << "p, q after if: " << p << ", " << q << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   StaticTest st;
   StaticTest::callback(1,2);
   StaticTest::callback(4,3);
}
```

These are the results in the terminal with various compiler options:

```
jb@jbpc $ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
jb@jbpc $ g++ static-test.cpp 
jb@jbpc $ ./a.out 
p, q before if: 3, 3
p, q after if: 3, 3
p, q before if: 10, 10
p, q after if: 10, 10
jb@jbpc $ g++ -O1 static-test.cpp
jb@jbpc $ ./a.out 
p, q before if: 3, 3
p, q after if: 100, 3
p, q before if: 7, 7
p, q after if: 100, 7
```

Comment: why do you think the output is wrong? What else did you expect?

Comment: Totally unrelated side note: Code you do not write has no bugs. If you have constructors, destructors or special member functions that do nothing, leave them out (the compiler will generate what's needed) or default them (eg: ~StaticTest() = default;) and provide no definition (compiler did it for you). Trying to outsmart the compiler ends in pain far more often than it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
float p;
static float q;

p += xpos;
```

The variable `p` is unititalized and using its value in `p += xpos;` invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Jørgen you should pay attention to your compiler warnings